# Variable length argument list to function?

Tags: java

I have received a Java library that has a class with the following function.   I have never used this type of function before so I am not sure what it is called or how to use it.

```
class SomeTree {

      public void setNode (Node... nodes) {
      }  
   }
```

Correct me if I am wrong, but the method will accept multiple arguments, right ?
If I don't know the number of arguments in advance, how will I call it ?

Suppose I have a "Node[ ] nodeArray" to pass to the setNode().   How would I do that ?

Comment: Thank you everyone for answering.  I learn something new today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compiler make the adapation (array to var-args) automatically for you.

All you need to do is to merely pass your arrays as the unique argument.

```
Node[] myNodeArray = ........  
setNode(myNodeArray);
```

Answer (score 2):

Correct, it will accept any number of Node parameters separated by a comma, or it will take a Node array.

```
Node[] nodes = createNodeArray();
obj.setNodes(nodes);
```

OR

```
Node node1 = createNode();
Node node2 = createNode();
obj.setNodes(node1, node2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will accept any number of Node instances. (this has var args) so you can simply pass the array or list of nodes when you invoke the method as follows.

```
setNode (nodeArray) or setNode (node1,node2,node3);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's called the [*varargs*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) syntax. It allows you to pass 0-n parameters of the specified type.

Within the method, the parameter is an array of the specified type, which will be of length zero if no arguments are passed in (ie not `null`).

You call it like this:

```
someTree.setNode();
someTree.setNode(someNode);
someTree.setNode(someNode, someOtherNode);
// etc
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html), nodes will be convert to an array if needed. So you can just call setNode(n1,n2) or setNode(arrayOfNodes)